# SimpleXML: Parsing nodes with value and other nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

Having an issue parsing some XML from within PHP. A node contains a node value **and** other nodes. Is there a way to parse both?

I am consuming this via an API so cannot control the output.

```
<?php
$xml = '<root>
    <foo>
        bar
        <foobar>Foobar</foobar>
    </foo>
</root>';

$data = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($data);
```

Will output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(11) "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to treat the data values as strings and you can access them as normal elements.

```
$data = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "foo=".trim($data->foo).PHP_EOL;  // trim() to remove excess whitespace
echo "foo XML=".$data->foo->asXML().PHP_EOL;
echo "foobar=".(string)$data->foo->foobar;
```

Will output...

```
foo=bar
foo XML=<foo>
        bar
        <foobar>Foobar</foobar>
    </foo>
foobar=Foobar
```

Comment: Ugh. You're right. Even though `var_dump` doesn't display them, they are actually accessible.

Comment: `var_dump` and `print_r` don't work well with SimpleXML.